# Count number of bookings between a set of specified dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of bookings. I want to count how many bookings occur on each day, starting from specified check in date and check out date. Eg. if check in date was 10-06-2012 and check out date was 14-06-2012 I require a table like this

```
Date         Bookings
10-06-2012   1
11-06-2012   1
12-06-2012   2
13-06-2012   4
14-06-2012   3
```

I am struggling to get this working. I can count bookings in between the dates but not for each date between check in date and check out date.

Comment: Try doing a `SELECT COUNT(Bookings) FROM table WHERE DATE [between dates syntax] GROUP BY Date`. The key here is the `GROUP BY` clause, and the `COUNT()`. Together, these will count how many bookings occur on each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question. The query below assumes:

- Your `bookings` table has (at least) columns `date`, `checkin`, `checkout`.
- You are looking for bookings where `checkin >= 10-06-2012` and `checkout <= 14-06-2012`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT date, COUNT(*)
FROM bookings
WHERE checkin >= '2012-06-10' AND checkout <= '2012-06-14'
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM()` to find total bookings between a date range.

Try Below :

```
SELECT Date,SUM(Bookings) 
FROM tablename
WHERE Date between 'startdate' AND 'enddate' 
GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need is a table of dates, day by day. Now mysql is not my thing, so I will try to write down as much info on what I'm doing as I can. Please correct these examples.

Table of dates might be prepared by a job checking for the last booking date and adding missing dates to table of dates. If this is not something you would accept, other solution is to create table dynamically, but there are some perils. To my knowledge there is no way to create such a table, but you can do a practically-working surrogate by selecting distinct dates from your booking table and cross joining this with table of days made in query itself:

```
((select distinct checkIn from bookings union select distinct checkOut from bookings)
 cross join (select 0 union select 1 union select 2 ...))
```

The list of days should contain as many days as the biggest gap between checkin dates and each checkin and checkout date. This is something you will have to keep an eye on, or simply make the list sufficiently large, for example a hundred days.

Now that you have a table of dates, you need to count bookings matching this date. Complete query would look like this:

```
select tableOfDates.date, count(bookings.checkIn) bookings
from 
(
   (
    select distinct dates.date + INTERVAL days.day DAY -- OR HOWEVER you add days in mysql
      from 
         (select distinct checkIn date from bookings union select distinct checkOut from bookings) dates
         cross join (select 0 day union select 1 union select 2 union 3 union 4 union 5 union 6 union 7) days
   ) 
) tableOfDates
left join bookings
   on tableOfDates.date between bookings.checkIn and bookings.checkOut
where tableOfDates.date between [YOUR DATE RANGE]
```